# How to display drag and drop image in a desktop PWA?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, progressive-web-apps

I implemented drag and drop in my progressive web app like in this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop) of the w3school. In Google Chrome you can see the element while dragging, in the installed Google Chrome Web App you only see an icon of a world.

[image]
*(Left side: Google Chrome Desktop Web App, right side: Google Chrome browser)*

Does anyone know how I can get the same behaviour as in the browser also in my desktop web app?

Here my code so far:

```
import React from 'react'

export function Selector({ id, onDragStart }) {

return (
        <div
            id={id}
            className="selector px-3 py-2"
            draggable={true}
            onDragStart={event => {
                onDragStart()
                event.dataTransfer.setData('chart_type', event.target.id)
            }}
            style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
        >
        <Icon className="chart" /> Line Chart <Icon className="menu" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Source code of the project: [Source Code](https://github.com/blicc-org/blicc)

Comment: Are you testing on the Desktop App with an internet connection or offline? I had similar issues once in my PWA, when not all the assets were correctly cached by the he Service Worker. Can you post your code parts involved?

Comment: @Francesco Thanks for the reply. I added my code to the question. I tried to use setDragImage with the target and also a simple image etc. but it just wont show it in the desktop pwa. So far I tested it only offline. I did not implement any caching logic in my service workers yet.

Comment: @Francesco I wonder if there is any simple example of a `<div draggable="true" > Drag me!</div>` which works in the chrome desktop pwa. I cant really figure it out since I thought they use the same engine etc. like in the browser. Caching is the only thing that could be different but there is no image to cache.

Comment: @thiloilg if you are using macOS or Linux, this behaviour is a defect in Chrome. Here is the link https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=880687
We experience the same issue. However, under Windows this works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instruct the service worker about which assets to make available in offline mode. Otherwise those resources won't be available.

With the code below, you can cache some resources (images in your case), while the SW installs. Therefore once the SW is registered on the client side, the targeted assets will be available in the cache and ready to be provided even without a network connection:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache';
var assetsToCache = [
  '/assets/myImage.png'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Access the cache...');
        return cache.addAll(assetsToCache);
      })
  );
});
```

If you are interested in PWAs, [I wrote a series of articles about them](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da), starting from the basics and then covering more complex topics.